# How to Consume WCF Rest Service with Android

Tags: android, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-client, wcf-rest

Here is code snippet, where I connect to my WCF Service.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();         
                            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(EMPLOYEE_LOG_IN);
                            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");          
                            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            if(entity.getContentLength() != 0) {
                                Reader employeeReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());       
                                                //create a buffer to fill if from reader            
                                                char[] buffer = new char[(int) response.getEntity().getContentLength()];        
                                                //fill the buffer by the help of reader         
                                                employeeReader.read(buffer);                
                                                //close the reader streams              
                                                employeeReader.close(); 
                                                //for the employee json object              
                                                JSONObject employee =  new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
                                                Log.d("Response",employee.getString("FirstName"));
```

It behaves different ways in different situation.
Here is code from my WCF Service

```
 public Controller GetEmployees(int personalNUmber)
        {                

                return new Controller
                            {
                                EmployeeId = 1,
                                FirstName = "FirstName",
                                LastName = "LastName"
                            };    
            }
        }
```

SO when I call  this method   everything works fine, I get json format well, but when I 
edited my method and connected into Entity DB like this

```
FineReceiptsTestEntities _entity = new FineReceiptsTestEntities();

        var t = _entity.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == personalNUmber);
        return new Controller
                   {

                       EmployeeId = 1,
                       FirstName = t != null ? t.Name : " ",
                       LastName = "LastName"
                   };
```

Json object didn't returned. Returned only html content with **error** like this

> server encountered an error processing the request.Please see the
>    service help page  for constructing valid requests to the service.

But both type of method in browser works fine and returns relevant data.

and here is my **web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
      <service name="dev_FineReceiptsService.ControllersInfo">
        <endpoint kind="webHttpEndpoint" contract="dev_FineReceiptsService.IControllersInfo" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FineReceiptsTestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/FineTest.csdl|res://*/FineTest.ssdl|res://*/FineTest.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=msdev01;Initial Catalog=FineReceiptsTest;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

So can anyone tell me what is the problem when using Entity to retrieve data ?

Comment: I used this example http://wyousuf.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/android-with-wcf-services/#comment-119 and worked fine but when I try to retrieve data using Entity Framework doesn't worked. PLease help, how to retrieve data using entity framework in Android.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your post to determine the cause. You must post the RAW HTTP response for anyone to help you. The server is probably returning a HTTP 415 since you are not constructing the request correctly.

```
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

You are setting the content type to json for a GET request. That is not possible. The server might be try to match that and get confused. It could also be that the server has a genuine HTTP 500 error from the request. From the way the response error is constructed, the service seems to be complaining that the request itself is not valid.

```
server encountered an error processing the request.Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.
```